# Order data - overlapping user IDs

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of user IDs with a line for each order giving order IDs and platform for the order.

I want to understand

1. Number of Unique Users shopping only on 1 platform,
2. Number of Unique users shopping on App AND in one of the other platforms (web-mobile or web-desktop) as well.

I have only manage to get the total number of platforms by users but I want to understand where the users overlap on platform.

I was hoping someone can point me in a direction for this one.

Sample data:

```
User ID Order no    Platform
1   12  App
2   123 Web - Mobile
2   234 App
3   345 Web - Mobile
5   456 App
5   567 Web - Desktop
5   678 Web - Mobile
5   780 App
6   789 Web
6   900 App
7   1011    Web - Mobile
7   1122    Web - Desktop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=faa7f5e770402f0dde6295ecdd0d1f92)

All users with only one platform:

```
SELECT
    user_id
FROM
    t
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT platform) = 1
```

All users with `App` platform and at least one more:

1. Aggregate all distinct platforms
2. Check if App is included
3. Check if array contains more than 1 element

   ```
   SELECT
       *
   FROM (
       SELECT
           user_id,
           ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT platform) platforms  -- 1
       FROM
           t
       GROUP BY user_id
   ) s
   WHERE platforms && '{App}'                      -- 2
       AND cardinality(platforms) >= 2             -- 3
   ```